# Issue with failure of loop to loop in VB

Tags: vb.net

So I'm writing a piece of code that has the goal of taking, for example, `coding @codez code @coderino` and turning it into `coding @CODEZ code @CODERINO`.

It works just fine if I only have one @ in the phrase, eg. `coding @codez code` turns into `coding @CODEZ code`.

However, if I have more than one @ in the phrase, such as in the first example, it ignores the loop and makes nothing uppercase, or simply breaks.

Here's the piece of code that I'm having an issue with:

```
Do Until CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol = -1
    CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol = StartingTweet.IndexOf("@", CurrentPositionOfSpace + 1)
    CurrentPositionOfSpace = StartingTweet.IndexOf(" ", CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol)
    TempName = StartingTweet.Substring(CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol + 1, CurrentPositionOfSpace - CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol - 1)
    TempNameUppercase = TempName.ToUpper
    StartingTweet = StartingTweet.Remove(CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol + 1, CurrentPositionOfSpace - CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol - 1)
    StartingTweet = StartingTweet.Insert(CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol + 1, TempNameUppercase)
    CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol = StartingTweet.IndexOf("@", CurrentPositionOfSpace + 1)
Loop
```

Comment: VB.NET and vba are nothing alike; pick the correct tag

Comment: This is a debugging problem (= too unlikely to help anyone else other than you, in fact not even you as far as asking about each single bit is not the best way to learn). The situation you propose is very simple (and your approach unnecessarily complex), just think carefully about what you want to accomplish and it shouldn't take you much (e.g., have just one index and make sure that you update the values properly between iterations). In any case, it seems that here you should better rely on something like `inputString = inputString.Replace("@firstword", "@FIRSTWORD")`.

Comment: The problem is, a replace would be nice but it's too simple; I don't know what the input will be so I can't just do that.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is break it up by spaces and then check each word, if it starts with **@** uppercase it. Then put it all back together:

```
Function FixString(item As String) As String

    Dim parts As String()

    parts = item.Split(" ")

    For index = 0 To parts.Length - 1
        If (parts(index).StartsWith("@")) Then
            parts(index) = parts(index).ToUpper()
        End If
    Next

    Return String.Join(" ", parts)

End Function
```